# creating a Dockerfile that grants ownership of any created files to the host user instead of root

Tags: docker, permissions, dockerfile, root

I am trying to create a Dockerfile that grants ownership of any created files to the host user instead of root. Ideally, I could share the image with others and maintain this functionality without requiring each user to build their own container.

I have been googling and Chat-GPTing but I can't seem to find an answer that works. Hopefully a human can help me.

Given this Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# start with ubuntu base
FROM ubuntu:22.04

VOLUME ["/data"]
WORKDIR "/data"

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "exec \"$@\"", "-"]
```

And these commands:

```
$ docker build -t image .
$ docker run -v $(pwd):/data image touch asdf
```

The file `asdf` is owned by `root` because that is the user running inside the container. What I want is a way to modify my Dockerfile so that any files generated inside the container will be owned by `$USER`.

ChatGPT told me to try using `gosu` in my `ENTRYPOINT` statement, but this didn't seem to work. The created file was still owned by `root`.

I also tried creating a new user inside the Dockerfile, but this user didn't have permission to modify the volume:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# start with ubuntu base
FROM ubuntu:22.04

VOLUME ["/data"]
WORKDIR "/data"

RUN adduser myuser
USER myuser

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "exec \"$@\"", "-"]
```

Any help you can offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please try something like the below sample

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Set the user and group IDs of the host user
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

# Create a new user inside the container with the same IDs as the host user
RUN addgroup --gid $GROUP_ID myuser && \
adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --uid $USER_ID --gid $GROUP_ID myuser

# Set the working directory to a directory accessible by the myuser user
WORKDIR /app

# Give ownership of the working directory to the new user
RUN chown myuser:myuser /app

# Switch to the newly created user
USER myuser


# These files are created to test the permission and  under which user & group 
 its created 

RUN touch vmss.txt
RUN touch vm.txt
RUN echo "Hello world" >> hello.txt
```

You can create the image using the docker build command like the following

> docker build --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u) --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(id
> -g) -t myapp .

Image names can be changed according to needs, the above is just a sample.

I have gone inside the container to check the file and permissions and user group adding the screenshot below

[Inside docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqL2U.png)

Hope this helps. please share your feedback here.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution would require each user to build the image with their specific values. Every user id on a system has its own value. On one server I am 1000. On another server, I am 1000984939.

It could be generalized to `docker build --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u $USER) --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(id -g $USER) -t image .`, but still. Each individual user would have to build the image themselves, which is less than ideal. I'd like to distribute an image via Dockerhub.

Comment: that was just an example hardcoded with user id and group id as 1000. will try to ignore these issues.